# Does anyone have any idea how HotSync works on a byte by byte level, Does anybody have any documentation on the protocol

Tags: palm

Over the past week, I have searched endlessly for documentation on the PalmOS HotSync protocol. I have tried many different search terms. I asked ChatGPT and it gave me some stuff on the packet structure

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  SYNC HEADER  |  PACKET LENGTH  |  MESSAGE TYPE  |  TARGET ID  |  SOURCE ID  |  DATA  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For clarity:
I have a Palm Tungsten E running PalmOS 5.2.1 with HotSync 5.0P
My goal is to write a website that utilizes WebUSB to sync information from the device,

I am able to communicate with the device:
Once I connect and run `device.transferIn(2,64)` I get the following bytes back

```
1,255,0,0,0,22
```

Repeating this I get

```
144,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,8,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

I am not sure what this means,

I can send data to the device after that but it doesn't respond, after about 30 seconds the operation is canceled by the device, USB is disconnected and program errors out.
I have tried looking through PRC files to no avail, I have tried looking through some of the files in pilot-link library on GitHub which gave me some info, but I cannot understand what it means. I have tried looking for IntelliSync documentation. The search for documentation is driving me insane.

Does anyone have any documentation on HotSync?

Comment: Here's some links that might have breadcrumbs to an answer: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PalmOS-HOWTO/coldsync.html
https://superuser.com/questions/1190871/heres-how-to-synchronize-an-old-palm-os-device-with-a-modern-64-bit-windows-pc
https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/1786-caple.pdf
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Palm
https://palm2000.com/projects/serialCommunicationWithPalmOsPart2.php
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/PalmOS

Answer (score 6):

The pilot-link library you mentioned should contain all the information you need.

For example, the [pi-dlp.h](https://github.com/unwiredben/pilot-link/blob/master/include/pi-dlp.h) describes the **Direct Protocol Interface** for the HotSync protocol

> Direct protocol interface to the device using the HotSync protocol.
>
> The DLP layer is the lowest interface layer applications can use to
> access a handheld.  It provides equivalents to Palm Conduit Development
> Kit (CDK)'s SyncXXX functions, as well as a number of convenience
> functions that are not found in the CDK.

The "internal structures" further down describe what goes over the wire. It looks pretty complicated, so I guess you just will have to work your way through it.

> My goal is to write a website that utilizes WebUSB to sync information from the device,

So convert the pilot-link library code to whatever language you are using. Somebody has already done all the work for you, you just need to pick it up and use it.